# org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: terminal.id of: com.domain.agent.Agent

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-annotations

I am getting exception while stating of spring boot server. second table(XYZ) which I want to innerjoin has 2 keys(AGENTID,TERMID) and AGENTID is the primary key in both the tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="abc")
public class Agent {

    @Id
    @Column(name="AGENTID")
    private int agentId;
    @Column(name="AGENTNAME")
    private String agentName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AGENTID", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Terminal terminal;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="xyz")
public class Terminal {


    @EmbeddedId
    private TerminalIds terminalIds;


}

public class TerminalIds implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3811257594320593004L;
    @Column(name="AGENTID")
    private int agentId;
    @Column(name="TERMID")
    private String terminalId;


}
```